# Programmatically select WarningNext Generation Parsers from a list of strings

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

How can I feed [Warnings Next Generation Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Next+Generation+Plugin) a list of strings that would activate parsers?

I want to have a common method in my shared lib that looks like this

```
  def withWarningNG(def listOfParsers, closure) {
    def result
    try {
      result = closure()
    } finally {
      recordIssues(tools: listOfParsers)
    }
    return result
  }


// And use it in various Jenkinsfiles thus:

 node() {
   mySharedLibVar.withWarningNG(['gcc', 'java']) {
     ... do something ...
   }
```

This would ensure that we always attempt to run the parsers even if unit tests fail the build. I realize that the parsers do not run when there's a compilation error.

I know that I could do this via the *Declarative* pipeline.  However, various routines we use misbehave when we try that approach.  As we migrate more build logic into the sharedLibrary declarative may become more useful.  At present, I'd like to do this in a standard pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass the string and execute it as a function easily via

```
def foo() { return "bar"}

def myFunction="foo"

"${foo}"()
```

So, we can create a method like so which accepts a list of analyzers.

```
/**
 * Run a set of WarningsNextGeneration analyzers
 * @param analyzersList  list of strings mapping to https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/SUPPORTED-FORMATS.md
 * @param closure jenkins pipeline code to execute
 * @return result of that pipeline code
 */
def withWarningNG(def analyzersList, closure) {
    def result
    try {
        result = closure()
    } finally {
        for (analyzer in analyzersList) {
            println "Configure Recorder for ${analyzer}"
            recordIssues(tools: ["${analyzer}"()], enabledForFailure: true)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Side Note: if a Jenkinsfile uses `return` to exit early then this approach will eat that return and it will not exist jenkinfile early